# How to upload multiple file on a dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, upload

I create a dynamic table. User may add and delete rows. In each row there is column for user to upload file.

`<tr><td><label><input type='file' class='upload_act' /></td></tr>`

I am using a `function` to adding `name` to the file upload because the table rows may change frequently.

```
function reCalculate(){
    $("#t_object tbody .tr_content").each(function(i){
        $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(i+1);
        $(this).find("input[class^='date_uploaded']").attr('name',"detail["+i+"][dt_upl]");
        $(this).find("input[class^='upload_act']").attr('name',"detail["+i+"][upload_act]");
    }); 
}
```

This is ho I process the submitted files:

```
public function save_activity_m(){

    $details = $this->input->post('detail');
    $i       = 0;
    foreach($details as $rows){

        //UPLOAD RULES
        $upload_name             = "detail[".$i."][upload_act]";
        $config['upload_path']   = FCPATH."assets/uploads/memo/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf|rar|zip|7z';
        $config['max_size']      = '2048';
        $config['file_name']     = $rows['dt_upl'];
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;        
        $config['overwrite']     = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload($upload_name)){
            echo "<script type='application/javascript'>";
            echo "alert('Oops something wrong. Please contact the admin');window.top.location.reload();";
            echo "</script>";   
        }
        else{
            $i += 1;

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Congratulaions. Your data is succesfully saved');window.top.location.reload();</script>";
        }
    }

    //echo json_encode($details);
}
```

I believe the problem is in `$upload_name`. But, I have no clue what's wrong. I need some enlightment.

**note**:
Ignoring the `IF`, the data is successfully saved, but, the file is not uploaded